# zoom in and zoom out navigation bar when scrolling in ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, zooming

Is there any way to achieve zoom in and zoom out effect the navigation bar like safari browser while scrolling in ios.

Comment: Make your custom navigation bar and then add an animation in `scrollViewDidScroll:`

Comment: thanks for advice .can we do it for default navigation bar

Comment: I don't think so. Make a custom `UIWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this litte framework will help you: https://github.com/andresbrun/ABFullScrollViewController